# jsoncpp linking error cmake

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, linker-errors, jsoncpp

I'm new to cmake. It worked pretty well, but now I get some linking errors:

```
undefined reference to `Json::Reader::Reader()'
undefined reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
undefined reference to `Json::Reader::parse(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value&, bool)'
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromArray(void const*, int)'
```

and some more of this type.

I think I have to add the library of jsoncpp somewhere.

Someone here with an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
target_link_libraries(your_exe_target_name jsoncpp)
```

Be sure that you've set up `link_directories()` beforehand.

Comment: [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:link_directories) is not a good way of providing paths to CMake - its own documentation discourages its use.  Better to use [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:find_library) and pass the full path into `target_link_libraries`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using 
https://github.com/nlohmann/json

It comes as a single .hpp file that you just need to download, put in the sources of your project and then include in the header file when you want to use it.

It is then compiled and linked as any other source file of your project, no need for any special CMake configuration!

Plus it is a great library for JSON that is really easy to use.

Comment: Link only answers discouraged on stackoverflow. Please include essential parts of the solution in this post